# intercept traffic generated by pktgen

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, tcp-ip

I'm generating traffic on a Linux host with `pktgen`. I thought I could intercept it with `tc` and apply certain actions, but apparently `pktgen` bypasses it and writes directly in driver. Is there a way to intercept packets from pktgen?

Comment: moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is not, because of where in the stack packet capture happens. pktgen operates below those hooks, so those packets can't be captured. At least not on that host. If you have a switch that supports port mirroring or span ports, or whatever terminology you prefer, you could mirror all the traffic and have a second host do the packet capture.